# how to autoload a self made config file in codeigniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter, autoload

I am unable to load my own config file. How can I autoload or manual load this file this?

```
    $psr4 = [
        'Config'                     => APPPATH.'Config',
        APP_NAMESPACE                => APPPATH,                // For custom namespace
        'App'                        => APPPATH,                // To ensure filters, etc still found,
        'Tests\Support'              => TESTPATH.'_support',    // So custom migrations can run during testing
    ];
```

Answer (score 4):

Create your configuration file in the folder **/application/Config** and define the class in the file **SomeConfig.php** like this.

```
<?php namespace Config;

class SomeConfig extends \CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig
{
    public $foo  = 'This is foo';
    public $bar = 'This is bar';
}
```

You "load" the class with this

```
$someConfig = new \Config\SomeConfig();
```

And you then use it with:

```
$fooMessage = $someConfig->foo;
$barMessage = $someConfig->bar;
```

I don't have to do anything to **/application/Config/Autoload.php**

Don't confuse "[autoloading](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)" in CI v4 with the CI v3 feature of "[Auto-loading Resources](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=autoload#auto-loading-resources)". They are altogether different things!

In v4 "autoloading" is about finding files based on the class [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

In v3 it is a feature that causes a class to be initialized (loaded) automatically when the framework is being started.

Comment: I've got a different situation, I need to load a custom configuration file within a custom Library, what will be the syntex? Is it the same?

Comment: @VipinKr.Singh The syntax would be the same as I show.

Comment: Unable to print $someConfig->foo; from view

Comment: (Autoload config file and print in view) -> Add $this->data['config'] = new \Config\HiddenConfig(); in BaseController then return view('welcome_message',$this->data); now print echo $config->foo; from view.

Answer (score 3):

@DFriend is right, I just can't find anything related to autoload config. But we can add this in the initController function in the \App\Controllers\BaseController, like below:

```php
public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // E.g.: $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
        $this->config = \Config\Services::YOUR_CONFIG_CLASS();
    }
```